# Xcode: How to set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1?

Tags: xcode5, nsthread, catransaction

I'm getting this warning in the log window of the debugger:

```
 CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.
```

I have to find out what code of mine is calling CATransaction so I can make sure it is running on the main thread.  My code doesn't call CATransaction directly. I.e. a search of my code for CATransaction turns up nothing.

In Xcode 5, what is the correct way to set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in the environment?

Thanks in advance to all for any info.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme

Select "Run" entry and then "Arguments" tab, and in "Environment Variables" add "CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS" as Name and "1" as "Value".