# CoreAnimation warning when updating NSProgressIndicator via a block executed on main queue

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation, nsoperationqueue, nsprogressindicator

I have the following scenario for exporting Core Data entities to JSON and displaying a progress bar while doing so.

*Sometimes*, after the sheet with the progress bar is dismissed when the export is completed, i get the follwing warning as a console message:

> CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction;
>   set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.

AppDelegate.m

```
//  AppDelegate.m

- (void)exportAsJSON:(id)sender;
{
    NSSavePanel *savePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];

    [savePanel beginSheetModalForWindow:[self window] completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
        WMJSONExportOperation *operation = nil;

        if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
        {
            [_progressIndicator setDoubleValue:0];
            operation = [[WMJSONExportOperation alloc] init];

            // setProgressCallbackBlock
            [operation setProgressCallbackBlock: ^(double progress) {
                [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^
                 {
                     [_progressIndicator setDoubleValue: progress];
                 }];
            }];

            // setExportCompletionBlock
            [operation setExportCompletionBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                // Insert code here to save data to disk
                [_window endSheet:_exportProgressSheet];
            }];

            [_window beginSheet:_exportProgressSheet completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
                NSLog(@"ExportProgressSheet completionHandler executed");
            }];

            NSOperationQueue *queue;
            queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
            [queue addOperation:operation];
        }

    }];
}
```

WMJSONExportOperation.m, a subclass of NSOperation:

```
- (void)main;
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = nil;

    // just for illustrating the problem:
    for (int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        sleep(1);
        [self progressCallbackBlock](i * 10);
    }

    [self exportCompletionBlock](data, error);
}

@end
```

So the first question is: It is just a *warning*, should I care?

The second question is, how to avoid the warning. There are questions on SO describing *similar* problems, but the suggested solution is often to manipulate the NSProgressIndicator only from the main queue. Isn't that exactly what I am doing with this code:

```
    // setProgressCallbackBlock
    [operation setProgressCallbackBlock: ^(double progress) {
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^
         {
             [_progressIndicator setDoubleValue: progress];
         }];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating the message further by [setting the CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25762396/2012262), I found, that the problem was not the message send to `NSProgressIndicator`, but the closing of the sheet, that I did indeed trigger from another queue than the main queue.

So this change fixes my problem:

```
[_window endSheet:_exportProgressSheet];
```

becomes:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^
   {
      [_window endSheet:_exportProgressSheet];
   }];
```