# CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction upon scrolling

Tags: swift, macos, core-animation, quartz-core, pxsourcelist

I have a Split View with a source list and a table view. All the data is loaded and displayed on screen.

I did enable [Xcode: How to set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867470/xcode-how-to-set-ca-debug-transactions-1) in my current scheme.

1. I start the app
2. All data is loaded and displayed
3. As soon as I scroll there is a **Crash**

I am not updating any UI in a background thread or doing anything fancy at all. Just scrolling triggers the error.

The log:

```
CoreAnimation: warning, encountered thread with uncommitted CATransaction; created by:
0   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff8aabf69a _ZN2CA11Transaction4pushEv + 318
1   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff8aabf19a _ZN2CA11Transaction15ensure_implicitEv + 276
2   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff8aac5719 _ZN2CA5Layer13thread_flags_EPNS_11TransactionE + 37
3   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff8aac5668 _ZN2CA5Layer4markEPNS_11TransactionEjj + 64
4   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff8aac712b _ZN2CA5Layer25set_needs_display_in_rectERK6CGRect + 333
5   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff8aac6fdc -[CALayer setNeedsDisplayInRect:] + 25
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff865759ac -[_NSTiledLayer setNeedsDisplayInRect:] + 210
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8662f4b8 -[_NSBackingLayerContents invalidateRect:] + 94
8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8635a249 _NSBackingLayerSetNeedsDisplayInRect + 160
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8635a1a3 -[_NSBackingLayer setNeedsDisplayInRect:] + 61
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8635a98b -[NSView(NSInternal) _setLayerNeedsDisplayInViewRect:] + 606
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8632888e NSViewSetNeedsDisplayInRect + 945
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff863284d6 -[NSView setNeedsDisplayInRect:] + 48
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff866d20e3 -[_NSMirrorDocumentView documentViewNeedsDisplayInRect:] + 266
14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9019fbbc __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9019fb4f ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 63
```

I am at a loss on how to debug this problem.

Comment: If you turn off `CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS` does the problem go away? Also, what does this have to do with PXSourceList?

Comment: @matt: The app does not crash but I get tons of lines of this when scrolling: `2016-07-15 19:31:18.001 Bigbucket[65476:2094312] Uncommited CATransaction. Set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to debug.` as well as a few of these `CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.`

Comment: Aha. Did you do a search on "Uncommitted CATransaction" on Stack Overflow? There are a lot of solutions offered.

Comment: Yes I did see those, but they're all loading data which should be handled in the main thread or doing an animation. But I am just scrolling and non of my code that I could possibly fix seems to be executed.

Comment: Could you please show us the CATransaction code?

Comment: @AlvinVarghese That's the thing, I don't do any CoreAnimation myself. I just scroll the list and then get this error.

Comment: And you are using Swift 2.2, Xcode 7.3.1 ??

Comment: Yes Xcode 7.3.1 and the latest swift.